# DB image rendering Issue in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I am facing an issues on rendering image properly in SSRS 2012 report when getting image from database with jpeg format. I am using expression in image as "=System.Convert.FromBase64String(Fields!imagedata.Value)". A part of image is getting displayed. Thanks in Adv.[image]

Comment: Why is the Base64 conversion required? I assume you're using a SQL Server database due to the Dynamics tag. Do [these steps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156342%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) produce different results?

Comment: beargle, the Base64 bit is because CRM stores annotation as a Base64 encoded string not a normal varbin(max)

Comment: yes kavin you are right, I am pulling it from annotation... but now it is fixed.. but there were several reasons for this issue i faced when troubleshooting... passing a filter ID from different dataset, from main report etc., i created a report with single dataset annotation and tried but no luck...  Finally it is fixed i clubbed multiple dataset quaries to one and it got fixed.. i donno exactly the behaviour of it..